# Scrapy: one row per item

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrape category pages for products from architonic*com. However, I would like to display these products in a csv one per row. In the current situation all the brand names from a given category page are listed under 'brand' while I would like to have an output like this:

```
    {'brand': [u'Elisabeth Ellefsen'],
     'title': [u'Up chair I 907'],
     'img_url': [u'http://image.architonic.com/img_pro1-1/117/4373/t-up-06f-sq.jpg'],
     'link': [u'http://www.architonic.com/pmsht/up-chair-tonon/1174373']
    }
```

I tried playing with the Item Loaders (added default_output_processor= TakeFirst()), adding 'yield item' (see commented code) and searched two days to find a solution without luck. Hoping someone is willing to help me. Any help is really appreciated.

My **output** looks like this:

```
2013-01-14 11:53:23+0100 [archi] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.architonic.com/pmpro/home-furnishings/3210002/2/2/3>
{'brand':   [u'Softline',
             u'Elisabeth Ellefsen',
             u'Sellex',
             u'Lievore Altherr Molina',
             u'Poliform',
             .....
             u'Hans Thyge & Co.'],
 'img_url': [u'http://image.architonic.com/img_pro1-1/117/3661/terra-h-sq.jpg',
             u'http://image.architonic.com/img_pro1-1/117/0852/fly-01-sq.jpg',
             u'http://image.architonic.com/img_pro1-1/116/9870/ley-0004-sq.jpg',
             u'http://image.architonic.com/img_pro1-1/117/1023/arflex-hollywood-03-sq.jpg',
             ...
             u'http://image.architonic.com/img_pro1-1/118/5357/reef-002-sq.jpg'],
 'link':    [u'http://www.architonic.com/pmsht/terra-softline/1173661',
             u'http://www.architonic.com/pmsht/fly-sellex/1170852',
             u'http://www.architonic.com/pmsht/ley-poliform/1169870',
             .....
             u'http://www.architonic.com/pmsht/reef-collection-labofa/1185357'],
 'title':   [u'Terra',
             u'Fly',
             u'Ley chair',
                 .....
             u'Hollywood Sofa',
             u'Pouff Round']}
```

I'm using this in **spider/archi_spider.py**

```
import string
import re

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector                   
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_entities 
from archiscraper.items import ArchiItemFields, ArchiLoader

class ArchiScraper(BaseSpider):
    name = "archi"
    allowed_domains = ["architonic.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.architonic.com/pmpro/home-furnishings/3210002/2/2/%s' % page for page in xrange(1, 4)]    
    # rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.', ),restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="right_arrow"]',))
    #       , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    #       )
    #            
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//li[contains(@class, "nav_pro_item")]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = ArchiLoader(ArchiItemFields(), site)
            item.add_xpath('brand',       '//*[contains(@class, "nav_pro_text")]/a/br/following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]')
            item.add_xpath('designer',       '//*[contains(@class, "nav_pro_text")]/a/br/following-sibling::node()[3][self::text()]')
            item.add_xpath('title',       '//*[contains(@class, "nav_pro_text")]/a/strong/text()')                   
            item.add_xpath('img_url',   '//li[contains(@class, "nav_pro_item")]/div/a/img/@src[1]')                     
            item.add_xpath('link',    '//*[contains(@class, "nav_pro_text")]/a/@href')
            items.append(item.load_item())      
            return items
            # for item in items:
                # yield item
```

**items.py**

```
# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/items.html
import string
from scrapy.item import Item, Field   
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import MapCompose, Join, TakeFirst
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_entities 
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader  

class ArchiItem():
    pass

class ArchiItemFields(Item):
    brand = Field()
    title = Field()
    designer = Field()
    img_url = Field()
    img = Field()
    link = Field() 
    pass

class ArchiLoader(XPathItemLoader):
    # default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    # default_output_processor= TakeFirst()  

    brand_out = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    # title_out = Join()
```

Comment: Please include your items.py file since this code will not run without it. :)

Comment: CSV? But you data structure is JSON. And so what's wrong? If you want separate list of items you should get item container at first and when extract needed data from it.

Comment: This is the output from Scrapy. No problem - I have a custom feed_exporter/pipeline defined in settings.py to export to csv.

Comment: Any solutions to solve my problem?

Comment: facing same problem ..could u resolve it?